# How to handle request, return and success and then process data

Tags: go

I created a new endpoint in go using the chi library.

The endpoint processes data for a long time (up to 1 minute), so I would like to return the http ok status immediately after receiving the HTTP request.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

```
package main

func processRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
// I would like to return ok status here


// here I would like to process data
}

func main() {
r := chi.NewRouter()
r.Post("/endpoint", processRequest())
}
```

Comment: Use a goroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a goroutine to process the data

```golang
func processRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
// Write answer to request 


// Start a goroutine to process data
    go processData()
}
```